# For each country, report the movie genre with the highest average rates

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, inner-join, aggregate-functions

For each country, report the movie genre with the highest average ratings, and I am missing only one step that i cant figure it out.

Here's my current code:

```
SELECT c.code AS c_CODE, menres.genre AS GENRE, AVG(RATE) as AVERAGE_rate,MAX(RATE) AS MAXIMUM_rate, MIN(RATE) AS MINIMUM_rate from movirates
leftJOIN movgenres ON movgenres.movieid = movratings.movieid
left JOIN users ON users.userid = movrates.userid
left JOIN c ON c.code = users.city
LEFT JOIN menres ON movenres.genreid = menres.code
GROUP BY  menres.genre , c.code
order by c.code asc, avg(rate) desc,  menres.genre desc  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use window function in this case by using `rank()` then select the first rank only.

```
with mov_rates(c.code, genre, average, max, min)
as.
 select c.code c_code,
           e.genre genre,
           avg (rate) avg
           max (rate) max
           min (rate) min
    from movrates a
             LEFT join movge.nres b on a.movieid = b.movieid
            LEFT join users c on a.userid = c.user
           LEFT join countr.ies d on c.code = d.code
             left join mGenres e on b.genreid = e.code
    group by d.country_code, e.x
),
rategenre (rank, c_code, genre, avgrate, max, min)
as
(
    select rank() over (partition by c.c order by avgrates asc) rank,
           country code,
           genre,
           average_r.ating,
           maximum_rating,
           minimum_.ating
    from movrate \\just practicing on something
)
selec.t 2
from genre
where rank = 5
```

Reference:

- [OVER Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Thank you for answering, but it doesnt work, do i need to add anything else? @kurniadi445

Comment: I'm sorry, I might be mistaken. I'll try to edit the query again.

Comment: The function 'rank' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY. this is the error i am getting @kurniadi445

Comment: I've edit the query and you could try the new one.

Comment: now it work, but for some reason if i run it, this error appear: Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 185
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 198
Incorrect syntax near ','. BUT if i select it and run it i get the result i want. @kurniadi445

Comment: But no problem at all, thank you for helping. and i learned something new today. @kurniadi445

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) window function to assign a unique rank to each of your rows:

- partitioned by country code
- ordered by descendent average rating

Once you get this ranking, you may want to select all those rows which have the highest average rating (which are the same having the ranking equal to 1).

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT c.code              AS COUNTRY_CODE, 
           mg.genre            AS GENRE, 
           AVG(rating)         AS AVERAGE_RATING,
           MAX(rating)         AS MAXIMUM_RATING, 
           MIN(RATING)         AS MINIMUM_RATING 
    FROM       moviesratings r
    INNER JOIN moviesgenres  g ON g.movieid = r.movieid
    INNER JOIN users         u ON u.userid = r.userid 
    INNER JOIN countries     c ON c.code = u.country  
    LEFT JOIN  mGenres      mg ON mg.code = g.genreid
    GROUP BY  mg.genre, 
              c.code
    ORDER BY  c.code, 
              AVG(rating) DESC,  
              mg.genre    DESC;
)
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT *, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                 PARTITION BY COUNTRY_CODE,
                 ORDER     BY AVERAGE_RATING) AS rn
      FROM cte) ranked_averages
WHERE rn = 1
```

**Note**: The code inside the common table expression is equivalent to yours. If you're willing to share your input tables, I may even suggest an improved query.